# CoordinatorLayout parallax with view group / LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- Use `layout_collapseMode="parallax"` on LinearLayout(or a View Group)
- Facing an issue where when scrolling down, the toolbar goes up and disappears.

I'm basically trying to accomplish this example with a View Group. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-parallax-animations

My code is as below. Any ideas what I could try? I am trying to accomplish similar to what [Habitica app](https://www.google.com/search?q=habitica+app&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyxPyV7Z3OAhXC6oMKHSqJBwwQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=860#imgrc=7QHFfVJNrobVtM%3A) does.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/large_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/large_padding"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/app_blue_active"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/picture"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_profile"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_profile"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_temp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/favorite_breed"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/experience"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/age"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/rating"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
                        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:rating="2.25"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/background_white_bottom_border"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary_font"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/secondary_font"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: this is just a suggestion from an amateur. Try giving a height and width to the toolbar which you have included. And also for temporary testing purpose try giving your toolbar a color and don't keep it transparent.

Comment: @SaranSankaran Thanks for suggestion. I'm already doing that.

Comment: Did you try specifying the width and height in include tag of toolbar? if yes what was the outcome?

Comment: @SaranSankaran I replaced the <include> with actual toolbar. There is no difference in the outcome. The LinearLayout takes the space of toolbar.